# ¿como establecer una conexión dinámica en un modelo de laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Estoy desarrollando un paquete para laravel.

En este paquete puedes configurar si quieres que las migraciones se hagan hacia una **DB** dedicada.
Por tal motivo hice un archivo de configuración donde se especifica la conexión.

```
    "connection" => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
```

Esta es muy fácil de recuperar en una migración. Pero no se como especificarla en un modelo.

```
<?php

namespace TrakerEmail\App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Content extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'mysql;

    protected $fillable = [
        "from", "name", "subject", "view_path", "user_id"
    ];

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->connection = config('traker_email.connection');

    }
}
```

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a
> default value (SQL: insert into `html_emails` (`updated_at`,
> `created_at`) values (2020-06-25 02:02:41, 2020-06-25 02:02:41))

Pero al hacer esto no se que pasa en el modelo dado que da un error.

Si no intento modificar dinamicamente la conexion ejecuta el siguiente query

```
insert into `html_emails` 
(
`view_path`, 
`user_id`,
`from`, 
`name`, 
`subject`, 
`updated_at`, 
`created_at`
) 
values 
(
uploads.email-376cd708-bcb6-4085-9df9-3d9523761df9.blade.php, 
1, 
jorge@gmail.com,
Jorge, 
Prueba, 
2020-06-25 02:25:15, 
2020-06-25 02:25:15
)
```

Comment: Que campos contiene la tabla `html_emails`? **Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value** aca indica que el campo `user_id` no tiene valor por defecto, es decir debes incluirlo en el insert

Comment: Amm si tiene el $fillable. actualizo la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

El problema que tenia es que estaba pasando mal los argumento al constructor del padre.

```
<?php

namespace TrakerEmail\App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Content extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'mysql;

    protected $fillable = [
        "from", "name", "subject", "view_path", "user_id"
    ];

    public function __construct(array $attributes = array())
    {
        parent::__construct($attributes);
        $this->connection = config('traker_email.connection');

    }
}
```

Al pasar los atributos al contructor de la model esta construye el modelo HTMLEmail correctamente.

Se me olvido que siempre se construye primero la clase de la cual estoy extendiendo y después la clase en la que estoy.